# How can I use equality in xt::filter?

Tags: c++, xtensor

the following code,

```
#include <iostream>

#include "xtensor/xadapt.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xindex_view.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xmasked_view.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    xt::xarray<float> a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 6}, {9, 0, 2}};
    cout << a << endl;
    xt::filter(a, a == 2) = 10;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Fails to compile with the following: `error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘xt::xarray<float>’` ... `and ‘int’)`

However, other comparison operators work as expected (>,<,>=,<=). I'm not sure if operator== was intentionally not implemented, but until it is (if it ever is), is there a work around, and what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xt::equal(a, b)` instead of `a == b`. I.e.

```cpp
xt::filter(a, xt::equal(a, 2)) = 10;
```

does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

xtensor provides logical operators like `&&` and `||`. Combining these with the allowed comparisons results in the same output as expected by '==' or '!='.

specifically `a >= 2 && a <= 2` <=> `a == 2` and `a > 2 || a < 2` <=> `a != 2`

so my final program is

```
#include <iostream>

#include "xtensor/xadapt.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xindex_view.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xmasked_view.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    xt::xarray<float> a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 6}, {9, 0, 2}};
    cout << a << endl;
    xt::filter(a, a >= 2 && a <= 2) = 10;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

and it's output is

```
{{ 1.,  2.,  3.},
 { 4.,  2.,  6.},
 { 9.,  0.,  2.}}
{{  1.,  10.,   3.},
 {  4.,  10.,   6.},
 {  9.,   0.,  10.}}
```